# Is there a shortcut to "Script to Clipboard" in SSMS

Tags: ssms

Do you know how can I set shortcut for SCRIPT to Clipboard?
I can't find anything relating to this in Options -> Keyboard.

Thanks for help.

[image: Select to Clipboard]

Comment: With the keyboard, how would SSMS know what object you are referring to?

Comment: On active object in object explorer? Exactly how this menu works.

Comment: So you've already moved your mouse to navigate the the menu and right clicked..? What's the point now? You might as well do the 2 additional clicks (they aren't a hardship). Keyboard Shortcuts are normally there to *avoid* mouse use. :)